# Locking screen orientation isn't permanent (android:screenOrientation="portrait")

Tags: android

Let's say Activity A has portrait set in manifest, and Activity B has unspecified in manifest. It seems that once I used setRequestedOrientation in Activity B, then popping the back stack to Activity A has activity A in landscape. Is this expected behavior? Does that mean that setRequestedOrientation would possibly change behavior of what's specified in AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 0):

If you're manually modifying the orientation using `setRequestedOrientation` in Activity B, I think you need to manually handle the orientation in Activity A.

You can force an activity to always be one orientation by putting:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Right above your `setContentView` call.

Answer (score 0):

As answerd before you should use

`setRequestedOrientation`(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

If you want all your activities to be, let's say, Portrait, create an abstract Base Activity and extend it in all your activities